# PostgreSQL statement_timeout *hard* limit

Tags: postgresql

I can set the global `statement_timeout` parameter on my PostgreSQL (14+) database to automatically kill long running queries.

However, the clients can override it and set their own `statement_timeout` that is significantly longer than the server one.

What I'd like to do is let clients set their statement_timeout **up to** the global limit, but if they go over it - either complain when they try to set a larger value, or just set `max(global_timeout, session_timeout)`

I don't *think* this is currently possible in postgresql, but I could be missing something.

--

My reasoning here is that I never want something hitting the high performance OLTP database that is going to bog resources for terribly long.  However we have client software that is automatically setting really long statement_timeouts and overriding the global settings, and then abusing the server - running reports which take many hours to process, that should be run on the backend ERP database, for example.

I'd like to enforce: "If your query really needs to take more than 10 minutes to run - you should be running it somewhere else".

--

If we can't do this in pg directly, could we do it in pgbouncer, or pgpool, or rds proxy?

Comment: In pgbouncer, you can use ignore_startup_parameters, but that only works if the parameter is set in the startup packet, which I doubt is what your bad client does.  If your client software misbehaves, maybe you should just ban it from the connecting to that system altogether.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, the only way would be to modify the PostgreSQL source.

You could regularly run a statement that cancels long running statements:

```
SELECT pg_cancel_backend(pid)
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE backend_type = 'client backend'
  AND state = 'active'
  AND state_change < clock_timestamp() - INTERVAL '10 minutes';
```